# GUI Builder for Swift on Linux/Windows

Tags: linux, swift, windows, user-interface, interface-builder

For an uni project my group was assign to develop an inventory management app (web or desktop) using swift language.

None of us owns nor is planning to own an Apple device.

After some searching I found out about Xcode, unsurprisingly it only runs on Mac OS.

Are there any alternatives for drag 'n drop GUI builders for switf on Windows/Linux? Building the GUI by hand defeats the purpose of this class, so if there is no alternative another language will probably be assigned to our group.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Virtual Machine running an OSX. 
I already used [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). The only problem is that the VM could stop or freeze sometimes, but for Linux or Windows I believe that is the only solution until now.